# Magento site, instead of executing, the index.php file is being downloaded

Tags: xampp

I have some doubts regarding Magento CMS website local machine deployment using XAMPP. I have configured all the files correctly, but instead of executing, my site is downloading the index.php file.

Anybody know what kind of error this is, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.